# selenium eclipse seleniumWebDriverException

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

learning selenium here is the code followed by error.

```
package com.selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WebDriverTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.wikipedia.org/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("searchInput")).sendKeys("selenium software");
        driver.findElement(By.name("go")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mw-search-results li:nth-of-type(1) a")).click();
    }

}
```

I get the error, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Admin\workspace\Session (The system cannot find the file specified)
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'Compaq-02', ip: '192.168.1.118', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.onlyOverrideThisIfYouKnowWhatYouAreDoing(FirefoxProfile.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:86)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:79)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.getProfile(FirefoxDriver.java:266)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:243)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:197)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
        at com.selenium.WebDriverTest.main(WebDriverTest.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Admin\workspace\Session (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.onlyOverrideThisIfYouKnowWhatYouAreDoing(FirefoxProfile.java:129)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Hi i'm using the latest 26.0

Comment: Do you have firefox installed somewhere besides the default location?

Comment: Corrupt JAR download? It's attempting to find the default preferences for the firefox profile, but cannot find them: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c378f5f654eefb85735730c4b68667a2fb7864a7/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.java#L131

Comment: @barak manos, also suggested that perhaps the jar file isn't for the correct OS. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Have you set environment variables for Java?